# ssh from username1@client to host using username2@destination

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, rsync, linux, ssh-keys

Forgive the possibly simple question, but I cannot seem to find a good solution.

A backup job needs to rsync files to a destination host, over ssh. The only login available to me is username2@destination. I do not have access to the sshd logs on the destination.

I need to run this backup using username1@client username. I am very familiar with using ssh-keys, when username is the same on both ends.

Is it possible to use ssh-keys when usernames differ on either end?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you use key based logins, the username doesn't get used at all. Logging in from `user@host1` to `user2@host2` with key based logins is quite a standard procedure. I do it dozens of time every single day.

You just have to make sure that the public key for `user@host1` is present in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file of `user2@host2`.

Comment: Thanks. So I have scp'ed user@host1 .pub file up to .scp/authorized_keys2 file on host2:

scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub user2@host2:/user/.ssh/authorized_keys2

I logged out, and tried to ssh back to it:

host1:.ssh user$ ssh -l user2 host2
user2@host's password:

So something is up.

Logs from client (ssh -vvv) show:

debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'

Comment: The error message says the home directory for `user2@host2` is `/Users/user`, yet you copy the public key to `/user/.ssh` instead of  `/Users/user/.ssh`. Try with `scp ~/.ssh/id_da.pub user2@host2:~/.ssh/autorized_keys2`.

Comment: Sorry, that comment was badly formatted. 


Logs from client (ssh -vvv) show the following http://pastebin.com/uB8vmWKp

Comment: I found the issue. I can't explain fully but the ssh daemon is running in an "unusual" location and I had to transfer the id_dsa.pub file to a different location other than user2/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Also, it seem the host is running an older version of sshd.

thanks.